# Can a hyperbolic quadrilateral have 3 obtuse angles and 3 equal sides?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Can a hyperbolic quadrilateral have 3 obtuse angles and 3 equal sides? I have been trying to visually see if that is possible or not.

Comment: Do you ask about hyperbolic **plane,** or ?

Comment: Not in hyperbolic space, but you can in elliptical space: just try to deform the second quadrilateral in elliptical geometry into the one you are imagining.